# Removing Listener from Panel

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

is it possible to remove a Listener from an Ext.Panel after the call? 
I have a tap-Listener, which I want to remove after calling the first time. I tried many ways to remove the Listener but it's still calling:

```
registerListeners: function()
{
   // this = Ext.Controller 
   // this.view = Ext.Panel
    this.view.on('tap', this.onTap, this, {element: 'body'});
},

unregisterListeners: function(evt, el, o)
{   
    console.log("Removing Event...");
    this.view.el.un('tap', this.onTap, this);   // Don't work, on the next tap its still calling
},

onTap: function(evt, el, o)
{
    Ext.ControllerManager.get('mycontroller').unregisterListeners();
}
```

I'm really confused?!? :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you notice that you are setting the listener on this.view but unsetting it on this.view.el? Is that intentionally?

Comment: Oh it's wrong, I've to test it again with this.view.getEl().on and this.panel.getEl().removeListener

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can set the single option in the on/addListener call.

```
myButton.on('click', function(){ 
    /* do stuff */ 
}, this, { single : true });

// In your case:
this.view.on('tap', this.onTap, this, {element: 'body', single: true});
```

Check the docs for addListener on http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/?class=Ext.Component

Comment: Oh, you are right but it's still calling?!? this is really odd... maybe a bug? Have you tested it?

Comment: I've used the single:true option several times yes, but i don't know what else is involved in your app, is it public somewhere were we can check?

Comment: I've tested it in a seperate project and it works. Maybe it's an other component or lib which conflict with sencha. Thx again :)